# Get OAuth2 Token in XML format from Mule OAuth2 provider; currently it returns it as JSON

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, mule, mule-studio

I have implemented OAuth2 provider using Mule Password grant type flow as shown on https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Creating+an+OAuth+2.0a+Web+Service+Provider. But it is returning token response in JSON format; I want it in XML format how can I do that ?

```
    <spring:beans>     
        <ss:authentication-manager id="resourceOwnerAuthenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="resourceOwnerUserService">
                    <ss:user name="user" password="password" authorities="RESOURCE_OWNER" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider> 
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
            name="resourceOwnerSecurityProvider"
            delegate-ref="resourceOwnerAuthenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>

<oauth2-provider:config
        name="oauth2Provider"
        providerName="SampleAPI"
        supportedGrantTypes="RESOURCE_OWNER_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS"
        port="8083"
        authorizationEndpointPath="sampleapi/api/authorize"
        accessTokenEndpointPath="sampleapi/api/token"
        resourceOwnerSecurityProvider-ref="resourceOwnerSecurityProvider"
        scopes="READ_RESOURCE POST_RESOURCE" doc:name="OAuth provider module">
            <oauth2-provider:clients>
                <oauth2-provider:client clientId="myclientid3" secret="myclientsecret"
                                        type="CONFIDENTIAL" clientName="Mule Bookstore" description="Mule-powered On-line Bookstore">
                    <oauth2-provider:redirect-uris>
                        <oauth2-provider:redirect-uri>http://localhost*</oauth2-provider:redirect-uri>
                    </oauth2-provider:redirect-uris>
                    <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
                        <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>PASSWORD</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
                    </oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
                    <oauth2-provider:scopes>
                        <oauth2-provider:scope>READ_RESOURCE</oauth2-provider:scope>
                        <oauth2-provider:scope>POST_RESOURCE</oauth2-provider:scope>
                    </oauth2-provider:scopes>
                </oauth2-provider:client>
            </oauth2-provider:clients>
    </oauth2-provider:config>
```

Comment: Why would you need in and xml format. ?

Comment: Because My RAML Services are in XML format and I  want token to be in that format so that I dont need o have one formats for OAuth2 token and another format for REST Services. Can it possible. OAuth2 Provider with SPring Security has that capability. Can it possible in Mule OAuth2 implementation ?

Comment: I Hope you need only the OAuth token . In that case you can encapsulate the component that calls retrieves the Token i a message enricher and then set only the token to the FlowVariables and use them whenever you need in the flow . Will that work for your use case ?

Comment: Thank you Neeraj. Actually in my requirement only OAuth2 and REST service is hosted on Mule ESB. REST consumer is are multiple that is Java based and Microsoft SSIS based; I need token in XML format as well.

Comment: Hello Naveen, Isn't it possible ?   As my Services are communicating using XML I would like to have TOKEN response in XML format as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to do this you need create a choice at the end of the flow, and then if the 'Accept' header is equal 'application/xml' you put a custom transformer from json to xml. Because the [OAuth2 Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1) says the token returned should be a json. I did it with spring security oauth2 but this is a customization.

Comment: Thank you Ismael. Could you please share code sample.

Comment: I studied more last weeks, 
what version of Anypoint Studio you are using? Because at Mule 3.7 you can just put a Transformer Message component in the to convert from json to xml. See an example here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-tutorial#one-to-one-json-to-xml-conversion

Comment: Thanks Ismael, I am using Mule 3.7, but when I put json to xml transformer in code I put in in this question, XSD validation is failing in Mule and My Mule app is failing to deploy.  I think Mule is not allowing json to xml transformation anywhere in <oauth2-provider:config> and <mule-ss:security-manager>. So I am unable to get token in xml format. Please correct me If Im wrong.

Comment: I get your point. Can you expose other authentication sevice, which call your current authentication service to convert the response received to the client?

Comment: Thank You Ismael I got your point but I dont have much idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a new http mule flow which invokes the oauth2-provider token endpoint and convert its response to xml.

create a new mule configuration file:

```
<flow name="token-json-to-xmlFlow">
   <http:listener> <-- new token endpoint
   <http:request> <-- invoke the oauth2 provider token 
   <transform-message> <-- json to xml transformer
</flow>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Vince. do you have any example that can be integrated with code I pasted?

Comment: just create a new flow that will invoke the token endpoint you have right now. http inbound --> invoke http token url --> transform json to xml